# Where does Kafka Connect store configurations

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

When I create a source or sink connector in Kafka Connect, where does it save the settings related to that connector? Are there files I can browse? We are planning to create 50+ connectors and at one point we need to copy them from one environment to another, I was wondering if there is an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect in distributed mode uses Kafka topics for storing configuration.

Kafka Connect supports a REST API. You can use this for viewing existing connector configuration, creating new ones (including programatically/automatically for 50+ new connectors), starting/stopping connectors, etc.

The REST API is [documented here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/restapi.html).

Answer (score -1):

> where does it save the settings related to that connector? Are there files I can browse?

Kafka Connect distributed mode is started with a property file - `connect-distributed.sh`. That property file defines a "config topic", value which is a regular Kafka topic where those uploaded connector definitions are stored. You can read that topic using `kafka-console-consumer` since it is just JSON content.

You then separately HTTP-POST JSON connector configs to the Connect REST API, ideally also using files rather than direct requests, and you can use GET `/config` endpoint from that later.

> planning to create 50+ connectors and at one point we need to copy them from one environment to another

If you want to load connector configs into different environments, I suggest you save the JSON files to disk rather than upload directly, or use external tooling like Terraform, Ansible, Kubernetes (e.g. Strimzi) to manage many connector configs.